# Xamarin UWP release freezes at 'Compilation of [number] methods'

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, uwp

I have a big issue. I use an obfuscation solution to protect my solution.
When I try to build the solution in "Debug" mode, it finishes in less than 2 minutes.
When I try to build the solution in "Release" mode, if freezes at 'Compilation of [number] methods.
There is more than 100 thousands.

What should I do to overcome this issue?
Can someone have a solution to this issue?
[Image screenshoot on where it freezes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzpdx.png)

Comment: contact the vendor of your "obfuscation solution"

Comment: I did. The option he gave was to deactivate the native compilation option in project property. It works. Thank you for your comment.